# Background api call without freezing user interface

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, nsurlsession

I want to call an api continuously with a time interval of 10 minutes in background without interrupting user interface and other api calls within the same app.

Like the api will update my location forever in backend database in every 10 minutes but this api will not interrupt the UI and the other api which will get called as I use the app.

Comment: use background thread or GCD or NSOperationQueue, but your beginner so better to read any tutorial about these.

Comment: Already there are lots of threads and please Google (Search the same query) before posting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Managing asynchronous calls to web API in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35573017/managing-asynchronous-calls-to-web-api-in-ios)

Comment: I want the api (which will get called every 10th minute from the launch of the app) gets called without interrupting the calls of other api and user interface. Not like going in to background and then come back to update the api ,I want that api to stay and get called for ever in background until I close the app.

Answer (score 0):

You should run the code in a different thread (called Queue in iOS). 
It's better if you read the documentation. Here I can show you an example, here I download an image in background and then I upload the UI:

```
 if let url = imageURL{
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async { [weak self] in  //background queue
                let urlContents = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
                if let imageData = urlContents{
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {          //come back to the UI Queue to upload the UI
                        self?.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

To understand each parameter and each possibility check the documentation.

Comment: I don't want any UI update with respect to the call of the api ,this api will get called in every 10 min to update something in backend database and some other api will also get called as usually as I use the app functionality.

Comment: Le Global queue is in background. You create it and put your code there. 
 If you don't need UI update you don't have to call the DispatchQueue.main but the logic is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can code like a recursive method to solve your problem. There is a solution below coded in Objective-c

```
- (void)myRepetitiveMethod {

   dispatch_queue_t q_background = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0);
                                               double delayInSeconds = 600;
                                               dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
                                               dispatch_after(popTime, q_background, ^(void){
//do something                                                   
[self myRepetitiveMethod];
                                               });
}
```

Goodluck